# Locate Dates within .txt file and Format them

Tags: string, vba, date, formatting

First off, I know there's a million questions about formatting dates, but I have not found a solution that works with my situation.

We are given a .csv file, and due to requirements, we must modify the file in a couple of ways.

Firstly, we run a VBA on the file in order to change the delimiter from "," to "|" (we have this working) using:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Z00393885\Desktop\csvStuff\"&myVar, ForReading)

count = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    strReplacer = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
    strLine = Replace(strLine, strReplacer, "|")
    strLine = Replace(strLine, chr(34), "")
    strNewText = strNewText & strLine & vbCrLF
    count = count + 1
Loop
Print (count - 1)
objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Z00393885\Desktop\csvStuff\"&myVar, ForWriting)

objFile.WriteLine "BOF" & vbCrLF & now() & vbCrLF & (count - 1) & vbCrLF & strNewText & "EOF"

objFile.Close
```

The second requirement is the one that's giving me trouble, I have to look for every Date that is present (they are formatted: 11/8/2017 1:30 EST and lie within the 10th and 11th columns) and format the date so that it would be 11/08/2017 (we need to remove the Time as well as make sure that the day and month has a 0 if its only a single digit)

Is this doable within the Do Until loop? or would it be better to have a separate function to take care of that part. Either way, I am not even sure where to start with manipulating Dates within a file like this and not just a variable

EDIT: here is some of the .csv file

BOF

11/1/2017 12:08:21 PM

3

Course Code|Home Org|...|Release Date|Effective Date|...|Web Address

123|TAD Sites|...|10/31/2017 00:00:00 EDT|11/14/2017 00:00:00 EDT|...|http://URL

456|DAT Sites|...|11/5/2017 00:00:00 EDT|11/5/2017 00:00:00 EDT|...|http://URL

EOF

Comment: Yes, it's possible in the `Do Until` loop; there's no reason to process the file twice. What specific problem are you having? I don't see anything that indicates you've made an effort to solve this problem yourself at all.

Comment: Please copy and paste as text the header row and a few records of the source .csv file.

Comment: @KenWhite All I have is an idea on how to go about doing this. My thought is to go through each line, as I already have this, and look for the slash symbols, and based on how far apart they are, add a zero? As I said, only a thought as I don't have experience doing file manipulation other than changing the delimiter

Comment: You have four relatively simple tasks to accomplish here: 1) Locate the date. 2) Copy it into a variable. 3) Modify it to the format you need. 4) Put it back into the string. So start with the first task. When you've got code that completes it, add the second, then the third, and then the last. Programming is all about breaking something down into small tasks, writing code to complete those tasks, and putting them together to do the job. So start with task #1.Figure out how you're going to locate the date value in code.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the advise, I have been programming for a while now, but still can get lost in the steps to take when it's language/situation I have not come across yet, I will try to work through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is split the original line into the columns, then you only need to consider the 10th and 11th columns:

```
Dim myArray() As String
'...
strLine = objFile.ReadLine
'Current delimiter is quote-comma-quote
strReplacer = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
'Replace current delimiter with a pipe delimiter
strLine = Replace(strLine, strReplacer, "|")
'Remove any remaining quote marks
strLine = Replace(strLine, Chr(34), "")
'Split line using pipe delimiter
myArray = Split(strLine, "|")
'Convert column 10
myArray(9) = Format(CDate(Left(myArray(9), InStr(myArray(9), " ") - 1)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
'Convert column 11
myArray(10) = Format(CDate(Left(myArray(10), InStr(myArray(10), " ") - 1)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
'Join line back together with pipe delimiter
strLine = Join(myArray, "|")
'Create one huge string containing all lines in file
strNewText = strNewText & strLine & vbCrLF
'...
```

---

To use this as VBScript will require a few minor changes:

```
'Dim myArray() As String
Dim myArray
'...
strLine = objFile.ReadLine
'Current delimiter is quote-comma-quote
strReplacer = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
'Replace current delimiter with a pipe delimiter
strLine = Replace(strLine, strReplacer, "|")
'Remove any remaining quote marks
strLine = Replace(strLine, Chr(34), "")
'Split line using pipe delimiter
myArray = Split(strLine, "|")
'Convert column 10
'myArray(9) = Format(CDate(Left(myArray(9), InStr(myArray(9), " ") - 1)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
myArray(9) = FormatDateTime(CDate(Left(myArray(9), InStr(myArray(9), " ") - 1)), 0)
'Convert column 11
'myArray(10) = Format(CDate(Left(myArray(10), InStr(myArray(10), " ") - 1)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
myArray(10) = FormatDateTime(CDate(Left(myArray(10), InStr(myArray(10), " ") - 1)), 0)
'Join line back together with pipe delimiter
strLine = Join(myArray, "|")
'Create one huge string containing all lines in file
strNewText = strNewText & strLine & vbCrLF
'...
```

I don't use VBScript myself, but I **believe** the `FormatDateTime` function will give you what you want as output.  It seems to be locale-specific, but I assume you use `mm/dd/yyyy` format as standard in your location.

Comment: The Split function is exactly what I need, thanks! The only unfortunate thing is that some of the fields do contain commas and quotations, preventing me from Splitting by the comma. Also, every field has quotations around it, which are removed by the 2 replace lines

Comment: This being said, should I run a second Do Until loop, splitting by the Pipe? this way, No extra commas or quotations are removed that shouldn't be

Comment: just realized that the line: strLine = Replace(strLine, chr(34), "")  will probably cause an issue and remove quotations that are in the field, is there a way around this? would the lines: strReplacer = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)    &     strLine = Replace(strLine, strReplacer, "|") take care of it for me and remove the second Replace line? (sorry for the barrage of comments)

Comment: Ahh - I had missed that - you are currently changing the string `","` to `|` - I had read that as you were just changing `,` to `|`.  I think I just need to resequence some lines.  Give me a second and I will post an update to the answer.

Comment: @johno - OK, I had to put most of your code back in. :D  And then the split / convert / join just gets tacked onto the end of your code.

Comment: This all looks extremely promising. I will have to play with things to make it work once I get in tomorrow since I am using VBScript on UFT, which doesn't like me specifying a variable As String or anything, cauing hickups. Marking this as solution however since it gives me all of the info I should need

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a VBScript version of the code as well as the VBA version.  (I was going to edit your question to replace the [vba] tag with a [vbscript] one, but that would invalidate the answer by @AssemblyRequired so I have left it alone.)

Comment: The funny thing is I originally had it as VBScript, but someone edited my question and changed it to VBA -_-

Comment: @johno I just looked at the edit history - the question started off with both [vba] and [vbscript] tags, but mentioned VBScript in the question.  The person who edited it to fix the tags probably should have guessed from that mention that it was the [vba] tag that was wrong, but the code is so similar to VBA that they appear to have thought that it wasn't VBScript.  (The only statement in the code that wouldn't work in VBA is the `Print` statement.  And the only other clue is probably the `vbCrLF` instead of `vbCrLf`.)  Oh well, the question got answered anyway, so hopefully all is good.

Comment: ah yes, I do vaguely remember putting both tags, I apologize for that mixup. I'm new to VBScript, so these slight differences can be confusing to me. As for the answer, yes, everything is working as it should. Thanks again for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about running a "text to column" function, simply altering the formats to the date columns, then outputting the file? This might be a lot easier than searching for characters and altering them the way you are doing.

```
With Range(pass the range here)
.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(..., ...),_
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Columns("x:x").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

From here you can save the file.

EDIT:

One caveat: you need to hard code the number of columns you will end up with into the array.

For example, if each row of the file contains 4 sections, you would use:

```
Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```